# Retrieve data from Firebase by id

Tags: java, android

I am new with firebase - I tried to get data by id.

I don't know why, for some reason it returns me null.

The code has divided into two classes.

The first is firebaseHandler - which sends the request to the firebase server and the second is the fragment which calls to the firebaseHandler.

this is my code:

```
//FirebaseHandler

    interface IGetStudentCallback{
    void onComplete(Student student);
    void onCancel();
}

public void getStudent(String stId,final IGetStudentCallback callback){
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(STUDENTS);
    myRef.child(stId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Student student = dataSnapshot.getValue(Student.class);
            callback.onComplete(student);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            callback.onCancel();
        }
    });
}

// Fragment
    Model.instance.getStudent(getArguments().getString("STUDENT_ID"), new Model.IGetStudentCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Student student) {
                currStudnet = student;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        });
```

[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Xr8.jpg)

When I'm on debug mode, I see that the section of "OnDataChange" doesn't run.

Comment: Add your database structure screen shot

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged done : )

Comment: so what the value of  `STUDENTS` and what is the value of `stId` you test with  and try use `addValueEventListener` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: I tried with student_id is 987..